# Maven add child of project as dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, parent

Imagine you want to add a dependency to your Maven project. That dependency is a child, which has a parent which is not included in your dependencies.

For instance, I have a project A, which has a dependency b. The library b is child of B. The library b has a dependency C.

The pom of my project A has this dependency (the library 'b'):

```
// pom of A    
<dependency>
    <artifactId>b</artifactId>
    <groupId>something.thisthing</groupId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The parent of b, B has a dependency:

```
// pom of B
<dependency>
     <groupId>something.thisthing</groupId>
     <artifactId>C</artifactId>
     <version>${theVersionOfC}</version>
</dependency>
```

And finally, b has a dependency on C, but no mention of its version, it uses the `${theVersionOfC}` parameter which is given in the pom of its parent:

```
// pom of b
 <dependency>
     <groupId>something.thisthing</groupId>
     <artifactId>C</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

My project A is not able to find the dependency C, because the version is not specified in the pom of b.

How can I now have a dependency on b, and tell b which version of C it should use?

Answer (score 0):

The artefact `b` needs to draw the version of `something.thisting` from somewhere. The notation suggests that the version is taken from some dependencyManagement. This could either be in the pom of `b` or in the pom of `B`. In the pom of `B` you mention a dependency which very much looks like it really should be a dependencyMangement entry. If you put the dependency in the pom of `B` into dependencyManagement, it should work (if the property is also specified).